# Why can I not su to root?

Tags: 16.04, sudo, root

I used `sudo passwd root` to set root's password successfully, then I tried to su to root, but it failed with no response.

```
ubuntu@VM-44-117-ubuntu:~$ sudo su root
ubuntu@VM-44-117-ubuntu:~$
```

You can see the username is not changed.

Then I tried to use `su root` but the username still did not change.

```
ubuntu@VM-44-117-ubuntu:~$ su root
Password: 
ubuntu@VM-44-117-ubuntu:~$
```

How can I make su run correctly?

Comment: The syntax is `sudo su`.

Comment: that ^ and `sudo su` is not for switching users.

Comment: Can you use `sudo` at all (for example `sudo parted -ls`)?

Comment: You might want to execute a `whoami` once you've executed the `su` command. Also execute `groups` to see which groups you are a part of. It is possible that you are already part of the super user group.

Comment: @jansma Please add output of `groups` to the question.

Comment: I have resolved  by reinstall ubuntu ,Thank you for answer

Answer (score 4):

The "root" part is assumed by default. So:

```
doug@s15:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for doug:
root@s15:/home/doug# exit
exit
doug@s15:~$
```

Of course, I (doug) am a member of sudo and therefore allowed to become root:

```
doug@s15:~$ groups
doug adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lxd lpadmin sambashare libvirtd
```

However, you can also specify the username you want to switch to. Examples:

```
doug@s15:~$ sudo su root    
root@s15:/home/doug# exit
exit
doug@s15:~$ sudo su richard
richard@s15:/home/doug$ exit
exit
```

For more information refer to the [su man](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/su.1.html) pages.

Now, with all of that being said, the behavior on your system does seem odd. If I take away user richard's sudo rights:

```
doug@s15:~$ sudo deluser richard sudo
Removing user `richard' from group `sudo' ...
Done.
```

And then, in another terminal, login as richard and try using su, I get:

```
richard@s15:~$ groups
richard adm cdrom dip plugdev lxd lpadmin sambashare libvirtd
richard@s15:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for richard:
richard is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
richard@s15:~$
```

So why do you get nothing? (which was your original question)?
Is your computer virtual, and hosted somewhere else? Often hosting sites do odd stuff for root and such. Does you version of su match this?:

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 40128 May 16  2017 /bin/su
```

Comment: sudo su can not swith user too

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid this altogether, and not compromise the security of your system. If you need a root shell:

```
sudo -s
```

Now, you are in a shell as root. Logout normally to get back.
Admittedly, there are a few times when having root have a password which works seems nice, like when you need to run a service like rsync to set up or restore things onto a networked computer. What I usually do in those cases is have the service pull instead of get pushed. For instance,

```
sudo rsync -a you@remotehost:/root_owned_dirs/ /root_owned_dirs/
```

If root permissions are needed on both sides, I try and set the root password on the machine with the least exposure to the outside world, and pull from the more exposed side. That way if I'm in a hurry, the mistake is on the harder to attack system.

In that case:

```
sudo passwd root
```

Set the passwd, then

```
su
```

and you have a shell as root.

My *secret agenda* is to **KILL the silly habit** of running "sudo su". This literally means,

> "Oh, computer, give me greater privileges than I have now, so that I
>   may ask you for greater privileges."

This isn't *terrible*, just silly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Just like you did before:

```
$ sudo su
[sudo] password for doug:
```

This prompts for the new password for root:

```
root@s15:/home/doug# passwd
[[new password for root]]
```

Exit like before

```
$ exit
```

Now try to log in as root with the password you supplied above

```
$ su
```